Hubspot Module Slideshow no longer "slides" and instead is in "block"
I am using hubspot for my employer, and im not proficient in their language yet. I have a custom module made by an earlier dev that i modified to use a Video for the bg on one of the slides. I have since had to revert that change and since then, the slides are staying in "display: block" style. I havent made any changes to CSS, There is no JS involved as far as im aware.
This is the code im working with. Im thinking it has to do with missing JS but im not sure here.
<article>
  <div class="hero-slider color-white {{ widget.padding_size }}">
    <section>
      <div
        class="hero-slider-bg {% if widget.with_overlay %}with-overlay{% endif %}"
        style="background-image:url({{ widget.background_image_01.src }});"
      >
        <div
          style="background-color: rgba({{ module.overlay_color.color|convert_rgb }}, {{ module.overlay_color.opacity / 100 }});"
        >
          <div
            class="page-center {{ widget.text_alignment_01 }} {{ widget.paddingmargin }}"
          >
            <div>
              <div>{{ widget.header_text_01 }}</div>
              <div class="margin-top-10">{{ widget.banner_ctas_01 }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div
        class="hero-slider-bg {% if widget.with_overlay %}with-overlay{% endif %}"
        style="background-image:url({{ widget.background_image_02.src }});"
      >
        <div
          style="background-color: rgba({{ module.overlay_color_02.color|convert_rgb }}, {{ module.overlay_color_02.opacity / 100 }});"
        >
          <div
            class="page-center {{ widget.text_alignment_02 }} {{ widget.paddingmargin }}"
          >
            <div>
              <div>{{ widget.header_text_02 }}</div>
              <div class="margin-top-10">{{ widget.banner_ctas_02 }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div
        class="hero-slider-bg {% if widget.with_overlay %}with-overlay{% endif %}"
        style="background-image:url({{ widget.background_image_03.src }});"
      >
        <div
          style="background-color: rgba({{ module.overlay_color_03.color|convert_rgb }}, {{ module.overlay_color_03.opacity / 100 }});"
        >
          <div
            class="page-center {{ widget.text_alignment_03 }} {{ widget.paddingmargin }}"
          >
            <div>
              <div>{{ widget.header_text_03 }}</div>
              <div class="margin-top-10">{{ widget.banner_ctas_03 }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</article>


Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you modified exactly? The transition to video cannot be your only change if I read your description. Javascript turns HTML into a slider but did it really work before with no JS?
